Sent BTC from my Taproot to Negative Segwit Address
Hey I sent my like $100 worth of BTC taproot address money to my BTC negative segwit address in phantom wallet. Looks like the $50k or so of Runes I owned went along with that transaction and is now no longer showing up in my wallet. Is there a way to recover this or send it right back over to taproot so that the runes show?
